# Mootools iterate over form and grep values for xhr-request

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-more

Is it possible to get all values from a `<form>` and parse it to mootools/json, so that I can use it in an XHR-request like:

```
var req = new Request.HTML({
 method: 'post',
 url: 'xhr_request.php',
 data: {
  formdata:       $('inputform').getdata(),
  someotherdata:  'hello world'
 }
}).send();
```

At the moment I have only text-input fields. In the json I like to have the input-name or ID as the key for the value.
e.g.:

```
<form id="inputform">    
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
<input type="text" id="company" name="company"/>
</form>
```

//mootools script parsing above to this:

```
data: {
'name' : 'John Doe',
'company': 'Joeys LTD'
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that works automatically if you pass the `$('inputform')` as `data:` - it will serialize it for you.

Comment: i found this meanwhile: var formstring = $('requestForm').toQueryString().parseQueryString();
var formjson = JSON.encode(formstring); is it what you meant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166042/how-to-convert-form-data-to-object-using-mootools

Comment: @abimelex You're overcomplicating things, just pass the `$('inputform')` as the `data` property, and Mootools will detect it's a form element and properly serialize it *internally itself*.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but I thin it will not work in my case, because I want to add same additional data to the json. Or is there a way to do so? (I updated my question to clarify it)