# Post request on Mootools

Tags: ajax, post, mootools

I'm new to MooTools and trying to send Ajax request with form content to the url.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= $PHP_SELF; ?>" name="fn" id="fn">
<input name="user_name" id="user_name">
<input name="user_mail" id="user_name">
<input name="user_text" id="user_name">
<input type="file" name="attach">
<input id="button" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('button').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        var req = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'url.php',
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on button, nothing happens. How right transferring data from form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, you had a `}` missing but aside from that you just forgot to add a `.send();`

Like `req.send();`, and you can actually pass the data as a argument to that method.

Test that and check [here about the .send() method](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request#Request:send).

Suggention to how your code could look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var req = new Request({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'url.php',
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        } // < --- You actually missed this one
    });

    $('button').addEvent('click', function(event) {
        req.send();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent works. How best to transfer the data from the entire form?

Comment: @gladooo, then you can [check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166042/how-to-convert-form-data-to-object-using-mootools). I will update here later when I have some time.